# How to calculate the hash of NSData in IOS efficiently

Tags: ios, md5, nsdata

Here is the solution,hope it helps.
If you know the nsdata is of less in size like photos small text files use method 1.
If you know the nsdata is large in size of like videos of some large text files, use method 2.

Method 1: If you know nsdata is less in size.

```
  - (NSString*)MD5:(NSData *) data
    {
        // Create byte array of unsigned chars
        unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

        // Create 16 byte MD5 hash value, store in buffer
        CC_MD5([data bytes], (CC_LONG)data.length, md5Buffer);

        // Convert unsigned char buffer to NSString of hex values
        NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

        return output;
    }
```

Method 2: If file or asset is large in size.(like maybe in >50Mb or even GB)

```
- (NSString*)MD5:(NSData *) data
{
    CC_MD5_CTX c;
    CC_MD5_Init(&c);

    BOOL didSucceed = NO;

    // Use default value for the chunk size for reading data.
    const size_t chunkSizeForReadingData = 32768; // 32KB

    long chunkSize=chunkSizeForReadingData;

    CFIndex readBytesCount = 0;
    long totalOffset=0;

    long dataLength=[data length];
    NSLog(@"filesize of data:%lu",dataLength);

    long dataTobeReadLeft=dataLength;
    while (dataTobeReadLeft) {
        if (dataTobeReadLeft<chunkSize) {
            uint8_t buffer[dataTobeReadLeft];
            [data getBytes:buffer range:NSMakeRange(totalOffset,dataTobeReadLeft)];
            readBytesCount=dataTobeReadLeft;
            CC_MD5_Update(&c, buffer, (CC_LONG)dataTobeReadLeft);
            dataTobeReadLeft=0;
            didSucceed=YES;
        }else{
            uint8_t buffer[chunkSize];
            [data getBytes:buffer range:NSMakeRange(totalOffset,chunkSize)];
            totalOffset = totalOffset + chunkSize;
            dataTobeReadLeft=dataLength-totalOffset;
            CC_MD5_Update(&c, buffer, (CC_LONG)chunkSize);

        }

    }

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    if (didSucceed) {
        unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        CC_MD5_Final(digest, &c);
        // Convert unsigned char buffer to NSString of hex values
        for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
            [output appendFormat:@"%02x",digest[i]];

    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: I think you should clarify and expand your question.  If your solution is intended as a complete answer, enter it separately as an answer; if it has shortcomings which you wish to be addressed, explain what they are so that others can provide their answers.

Comment: It is not bad to share your opinion on the problem, but please use the correct tools: at least write it as separate question and answer, also if that is your intent to do it - there's a checkbox at the bottom of the question creation form that lets you properly do so.

Comment: i will sure do it next time,thanks for the info.